# How would I go about deobfuscating confuserex on most amount of obfuscation?

Tags: c#, .net, deobfuscation, confuserex

If I had a confuserex application with the most amount of obfuscation added (max preset) how would I deobfuscate it?

Comment: If there was an easy way to do that, who would bother with obfuscation?

Comment: No one is going to help you with this; it's impossible to know your intent, and whether it is secretly nefarious. One of the few ways we have to protect our code is through obfuscation. If we found a way to invalidate that, it would hurt everyone in irreparable ways.

Comment: @Krythic I haven't seen a single case of obfuscation where the obfuscator was the good guy. In 100% of the cases, the obfuscation has either been for DRM or to hide malware.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica A company making sure it can pay it's programmers and a programmer making sure he still has soemthing to eat tomorrow are the good guys, at least for me. | Also if we break it, that would only result in **worse** forms of obfuscation being applied in the future.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Perhaps.  We can call it what we like but the concept of scrambling code so as not be decipherable is more popular today than it ever was for .NET.  One has only to look at JavaScript-driven web sites.  Now JS devs may not call it _"obfuscation"_ and they perhaps have a different primary goal but the net effect is the same.  I don't believe any of the creations I've observed are involved with DRM or malware either.  Merry Christmas to you good sir

Comment: @MickyD I view minification as distinct from obfuscation.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica as I said the _"net effect"_ is the same

Comment: @MickyD Any obfuscator that's even marginally effective today will do a lot more than removing whitespace and shortening identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

It is orders of magnitude easier to obfuscate something, the to de-obfuscate it. This question has a high likelyhood of having nefarious intent. And any practical help would just result in future obfuscation being way more agressive. A scenario worse for performance, debugging and reliability of hte obfuscated software.

About the only *theoretical* way I could think off, would having something like Visual Studioes/.NET JiT level code optimisation. They are capable of swapping out constructst for totally different, quicker ones. A optimsaition for speed. This would be a optimisation towards readability. But even that will not be able to recover names obfuscated with some placeholder name. But I do not want to think this any further.